# Enter column value based on another column of another data frame in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

df1:

```
    ID      
0   9712    
1   9920    
2   9712    
3   9560    
4   9560
```

df2:

```
     ID       Absent    Comp-off
0   9712    12/15/2021  
1   9920                4/11/2021
2   9712                08/30/2021
3   9560    07/3/2021   
4   9560
```

In df1, I need to create a column 'Status'. For an ID if any data is present in 'Absent' or 'comp-off' columns of df2 Status is 'A' else 'P'. How can I achieve it using if else condition?

Comment: What package are you using for your dataframes?

Comment: I am using the default package of python

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, it is not an optimized one, but it can do that job.

I recreated your `dataframe`s like this below,

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['9712','9920','9712','9560','9560']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['9712','9920','9712','9560','9560'],
                    'Absent':['12/15/2021','','','07/3/2021',''],
                    'Comp-off':['','4/11/2021','08/30/2021','','']})
```

and here is the solutions,

```
status =[]
for i,j in df2.iterrows():
    if j['Absent'] != '':
        status.append('A')
    elif j['Comp-off'] != '':
        status.append('P')
    else:
        status.append('')

df1['Status'] = status
```

Sample output:

```
     ID Status
0  9712      A
1  9920      P
2  9712      P
3  9560      A
4  9560
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
b1=pd.isnull(df2['Absent'])
b2=pd.isnull(df2['Compoff'])
df['Status'] =['P' if b else 'A' for b in np.array(b1&b2)]
```

And this is the sample output I got.

```
df

    ID  Status
0   9712    A
1   9920    A
2   9712    A
3   9560    A
4   9560    P
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Thank you.